# Pentaho: block this step until steps finish

Tags: memory, block, pentaho, out

I'm trying to use "block this step until steps finish" for a transformation but it seems to not work:

[image]

On the way it appears on the picture, it is assumed that "total EPOs. DAT, VSE, ESP" shoudn't be run until "Filtrar GESTIONADO ny" and "Select values Kibana 2" haven't finished, am I right? If not, how can I get such purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to make image as image.

Comment: i can not find the 1st two steps you specified in block step.check the name again.

Comment: "FilterGESTIONADO gcb" does not apply.

Comment: "FilterGESTIONADO ny" is on the firtst stream (at the end). The flow would continue (it is not finished yet as I could see that it was not working properly).

Answer (score 5):

ALL steps in a transformation start running at initialization. Then they either start processing their input or wait for rows to come in.

A "Block this step..." step does NOT prevent the next step from running, it only blocks rows going through to that step. This does exactly what you expect for steps that need incoming rows (like a Text File Output or Database Lookup) but doesn't do anything for steps that generate new rows from an input source.

Your next step after the block looks like a Text File or CSV input. That step will just start reading the file right away and generate rows.
With a Text File Input (perfectly usable for most CSV files) you can tell it to accept a filename from an incoming field. That way it will wait until the blocking step allows the single row with the filename to pass.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cyrus! I have just seen it. Could you add any clue for configuring the step "Generate Rows - Filename" please?

Comment: Just enter one field of type String and set the value to the full path and filename that you have in Text File Input now. Make sure to set the number of rows to 1.